# Using inotify to check if files in a watched folder are overwritten

Tags: c, linux, file, inotify

I have written a C program that uses `inotify` to watch a particular folder. I want to be notified when a new file is created in this folder, or if an existing file was overwritten (i.e. the folder already contains `a.txt`, and I copy a newer copy of `a.txt` into this folder, essentially overwriting it).

I am able to generate a notification when new files are added to this folder using the `IN_CREATE` mask, but I don't get any notification for the second scenario. I've tried `IN_MODIFY` and `IN_ATTRIB`, both didn't work.

Is it possible to be notified of the second scenario?

Answer (score 1):

If you overwrite the file you will not get the IN_MODIFY and IN_ATTRIB event. Because, the file is not modified and also the file attributes are not changed. The overwritten is equal to creating a new file. So, You can try that two events with separate.

IN_MODIFY:-

This event is occurred only when the file is modified. To notify this event, you can try to update or remove some contents in the watching list file.

IN_ATTRIB:-

This event is occurred only when the file attribute is changed. Attribute means file meta data. So, If you want to get this event for a file, You can change the file permission in the watching list file.

Make sure, you want to see this event, you have to add the following events in the event list, When your inotify is initialized.

- In_MODIFY
- IN_ATTRIB

Comment: For inotify the timestamp is not comes under the attribute, I don't know why. But I am sure, I was tried this case. I am changing the modification time of the file, but it will not give the IN_ATTRIB event. And also I was modifying a file, that time also the file modification time is changed. If you want to get the exact event with your program you can try with system built in command called "inotifywait".